# How can i pass conditional variables in custom directive Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass variable in my custom directive. But this gets false or undefined after load. Please help me to find the issue and guide me where i am wrong.

**Custom Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[air-btn]'
})
export class AirBtnDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() small?: boolean;
  @Input() outline?: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  classes: string[] = [
    'relative',
    'disabled:opacity-70',
    'disabled:cursor-not-allowed',
    'rounded-lg',
    'hover:opacity-80',
    'transition',
    'w-full',
    this.outline ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-rose-500',
    this.outline ? 'border-black' : 'border-rose-500',
    this.outline ? 'text-black' : 'text-white',
    this.small ? 'text-sm' : 'text-md',
    this.small ? 'py-1' : 'py-3',
    this.small ? 'py-1' : 'py-3',
    this.small ? 'font-light' : 'font-semibold',
    this.small ? 'border-[1px]' : 'border-2'
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.outline)
    this.classes.forEach((val) => {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, val);
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button air-btn [outline]="true">Continue with Google</button>
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: You say "But this gets false or undefined after load" but I will wager you're inferring that because your classes aren't being set as you expect rather than looking at the variables after load.  Your problem is you're trying to use the variable in the class definition before it is actually set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the classes array inside ngOnInit.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[air-btn]'
})
export class AirBtnDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() small?: boolean;
  @Input() outline?: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  classes: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.classes = [
      'relative',
      'disabled:opacity-70',
      'disabled:cursor-not-allowed',
      'rounded-lg',
      'hover:opacity-80',
      'transition',
      'w-full',
      this.outline ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-rose-500',
      this.outline ? 'border-black' : 'border-rose-500',
      this.outline ? 'text-black' : 'text-white',
      this.small ? 'text-sm' : 'text-md',
      this.small ? 'py-1' : 'py-3',
      this.small ? 'py-1' : 'py-3',
      this.small ? 'font-light' : 'font-semibold',
      this.small ? 'border-[1px]' : 'border-2',
    ];
    console.log(this.outline);
    this.classes.forEach((val) => {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, val);
    });
  }
}
```